Docker-compose failing to properly mount Ubuntu folders
I'm trying to rebuild my Docker setup on a new Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu 24.04.1) and am running into issues mounting folders that previously worked fine. In the examples below, I have /data/satisfactory/config as a host folder that is mounted to /config in the container. However, files that exist in the host folder don't appear in the VM.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  satisfactory-server:
    container_name: 'satisfactory'
    hostname: 'satisfactory-server'
    image: 'wolveix/satisfactory-server:latest'
    ports:
        - '7777:7777/tcp'
        - '7777:7777/udp'
    volumes:
        - '/data/satisfactory/config:/config'
    environment:
        - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
        - MAXPLAYERS=6
        - PGID=1000
        - PUID=1000
        - ROOTLESS=false
        - STEAMBETA=false
    restart: unless-stopped

File listings on host and in container:
❯ ls -ltr /data/satisfactory/config
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 3 jon jon 4096 Oct 27 20:22 logs
drwxrwxrwx 2 jon jon 4096 Oct 27 20:22 backups
drwxrwxrwx 6 jon jon 4096 Oct 27 20:22 gamefiles
drwxrwxrwx 2 jon jon 4096 Oct 27 20:23 overrides
drwxrwxrwx 4 jon jon 4096 Oct 27 20:23 saved


# Contents of saved file folder on host:

❯ ls -ltr /data/satisfactory/config/saved/server
total 52808
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jon jon 7495071 Oct 27 20:25 game-save_autosave_1.sav
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jon jon 7499844 Oct 27 20:25 game-save_autosave_2.sav
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jon jon 7498095 Oct 27 20:25 game-save_autosave_3.sav
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jon jon 7505447 Oct 27 20:25 game-save_autosave_4.sav

# Contents of folder location from within container:

❯ docker exec -it satisfactory sh
# ls -ltr /config/saved/server
total 0
#

The issue exists for three other containers with config folders in the same /data folder, which I truncated here. However, if I move the folders to a mounted network drive, everything functions properly.
Updated line in docker-compose.yml:
volumes:
    - '/mnt/vault/data/satisfactory-relaxed/config:/config' #NFS mounted share

Files on NFS mount (folder name is satisfactory-relaxed instead of satisfactory:
❯ ls -ltr /mnt/vault/data/satisfactory-relaxed/config
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 1 jon jon    0 Nov  8  2023 overrides
drwxrwxr-x 1 jon jon   52 Oct 28 06:41 logs
drwxrwxr-x 1 jon jon 1012 Oct 28 06:41 backups
drwxrwxr-x 1 jon jon  350 Oct 28 06:41 gamefiles
drwxrwxrwx 1 jon jon  118 Oct 28 06:42 saved

❯ ls -ltr /mnt/vault/data/satisfactory-relaxed/config/saved/server
total 52660
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon jon 7468573 Oct 28 16:25 game-save_autosave_4.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon jon 7462665 Oct 28 16:35 game-save_autosave_1.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon jon 7470903 Oct 28 16:40 game-save_autosave_2.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon jon 7479219 Oct 28 16:45 game-save_autosave_3.sav

❯ docker exec -it satisfactory-relaxed sh
# ls -ltr /config/saved/server
total 52672
-rw-r--r-- 1 steam steam 7462665 Oct 28 09:35 game-save_autosave_1.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 steam steam 7470903 Oct 28 09:40 game-save_autosave_2.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 steam steam 7479219 Oct 28 09:45 game-save_autosave_3.sav
-rw-r--r-- 1 steam steam 7479562 Oct 28 09:50 game-save_autosave_4.sav

It's clearly some kind of permissions issue but I can't figure it out. There are no obvious errors in docker logs satisfactory, and as you can see above I set the chmod permissions on the folders to 777 in an attempt to debug but that didn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Updated to clarify that it is Ubuntu 24.04.1.
